# How to change the date format within WhatsApp messages?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, date-and-time

In WhatsApp, you see the date as DD/MM/YY or MM/DD/YY and you want it the other way around.

How to change the date format within WhatsApp messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WhatsApp doesn't read the date format settings from Android's date format settings, but rather it adjusts the date format depending on the language set for the Android interface.

**Solution:**

- If you want DD/MM/YY, change the language of Android to English (UK)
- If you want MM/DD/YY, change the language of Android to English (USA)

Settings > Language & Input > Language (in the phone settings)